# Wamp - Phpmyadmin is not working when xdebug extension is loaded

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp, xdebug

I have installed Wampserver 3.1.7 (x64) and I'm using it with PHP 7.3.1.

When I enable xdebug through php.ini (Wamp icon -> Php -> php.ini), the phpmyadmin is not working anymore (can't access localhost/phpmyadmin).

This is not happening if I use PHP 7.2.14, which uses another xdebug version.

I just can't see any error on log files...